# Chrome extension and accessing Google Drive

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-drive-api

I want to access google drive from a chrome extension and it appears that Google provides 2 ways to do it.

One is via the google-api-javascript-client:

https://github.com/google/google-api-javascript-client

I cannot find the npm entry for this library. Can it be installed via npm?

The other seems to be via the google-api-nodejs-client

https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client

This can be installed via this npm entry: https://www.npmjs.com/package/googleapis

Can google-api-nodejs-client be used in a Chrome extension?

Comment: So essentially you want to use the JS Drive library in a node.js extension?

Comment: in a chrome extension